# Latex quetion "Missing $ inserted"

Tags: latex, equation

I want to write this simple equation in latex

```
    2/|w|
```

In which |w| is the norm of w,,

I tried with

```
     \frac{2}{\|w\|}
```

And get error "Missing $ inserted"

then I use this

```
  \frac{2}{$\|w\|$}
```

And still get same error..

Does someone know how to solve this problem??

Comment: There's a whole stackexchange devoted to latex: see tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Duplicate posted: [Latex question “Missing $ inserted](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168254/5764)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was asked and answered on Tex - http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168254/latex-question-missing-inserted

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because LaTeX recognized this as being part of an equation and tried to correct it automagically. Unfortunately that rarely works well. You need to tell LaTeX that this is an equation.

To round out @nicoguaro's answer, use this form for equations that will be numbered and stand alone in the text:

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{2}{\left| w \right|}
\end{equation}
```

Or, use this form for equations that form part of a sentence:

```
blah blah $\frac{2}{\left| w \right|}$ blah blah.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are this expression inside a mathematical environment like

```
\begin{equation}
...
\end{equation}
```

or $ $, \( \), \[ \] ?

The expression can be written as (using \[ \])

```
\[\frac{2}{\vert w \vert}\]
```

or just

```
\[\frac{2}{| w |}\]
```

You can see this [book in Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics).  You need to specify that the whole expression is a mathematical expression enclosing it in its delimiters.